# Why does my washing machine shift around while operating?

Tags: washing-machine

My washing machine shifts around slightly during the entire washing procedure. It doesn't move that obvious that I could tell what part of the washing procedure makes it do this. However, the obvious reason may be the spinning cycle.

My theory is that the washing machine tries to walk "downhill" and/or follows its balancing point. It shifts a bit to the left and comes forward slightly. Therefore, I thought that I can fix this by elevating the front left a bit and maybe the back left a little less than the front left.

Before I test this theory and maybe waste my time I thought I'd ask if this is true. Or where should I elevate the washing machine?

---

EDIT: I might add that the problem started after moving to my new apartment. Therefore, I think that it's not a factor of wearing out, but something like an installation alignment that I need to make. Since the bathroom was refurbished before I moved in, I might also deal with tiles that are still in motion and I simply have to expect to readjust the washing machine.

The current status is that it somehow "danced" itself into a position where it seems to be stable. So at this time I'm not supposed to push it too hard...

So this has turned into a theoretical "what-to-do-if"-kind of question. Is my actual question or rather assumption valid?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your washing machine should be level and all legs should be squarely on the floor.  If it's not, you'll have unbalanced forces acting on it as the drum spins.  During the spin cycle, these forces are much larger because of the higher spin speeds and will make it "walk".

You'll need a [spirit level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_level) to balance the washer.  There's usually a gap between the top plate and the side plate of the washer that you can rest the level in to measure the front-to-back tilt.  For the side-to-side tilt, generally just put the level on the top of the washer.  You may have lock-nuts on the legs: if so, loosen them with a wrench before trying to adjust the washer, and tighten them afterwards.  Raise or lower the legs until all four are solidly on the floor; the washer should not rock at all.  If you have to move the washer to adjust it, remember to check it once it's back in its place.

Comment: Uhm, ok thanks, but I'm not a total novice. I already did all of that, but my problem persists. So I'd like to have suggestions for the fine-tuning.

Comment: You didn't indicate that you'd done all that in your OP, so your rather offended seeming first sentence strikes me as rather unjustified.  People aren't going to want to help you if they think they'll just get their virtual hands slapped in response.

Comment: Your machine may have a "snubber", a part that acts as a damper on the tub's motion.   We has a washer that started wobbling significanly, and it turned out he snubber had worn down and needed replacing.   It was an inexpensive and easy fix, and solved the problem.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I didn't intend to sound offended, but reading my comment again I have to agree that it sounded that way. My apologies. BTW, sorry for the late reply, but I thought that after two or three weeks no more comments or answers would come in.

Comment: @TomG That sounds like an option, but it started after I moved to my new apartment. So at this time I think that it has got to do with the "initial installing routine". I will update my question...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I eventually worked out it was due to the feet having got dirty, thus affecting the contact with the floor. We have had to pull it out now and again. If you think this might be the issue, clean the bottom of the feet.  Worked for me...

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I cleaned them while moving to my new apartment. I will update my question...